# Making a directory upon registration

Tags: php

So i have a code to register and i want for each user that registers that he gets his own folder with same name as he registered and i dont know how to do that i heard there is **mkdir** but i m new to that so if anyone could help me out please where i should add that mkdir or something and whats the command!

here is my register.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';



if(input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 20,
                'unique' => 'users'
            ),
            'password' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 6
            ),
            'password_again' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'matches' => 'password'
            ),
            'name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);


            try {
                $user->create(array(
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'name' => Input::get('name'),
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1
                ));
                Session::flash('home', '<h3>Registracija uspešna!</h3>');
                Redirect::to('mojprofil.php');

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/mkdir My suggestion is you create the directory at the same point your `$user->create()` **was a success**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the username as a directory name, with al the security flaws related to that. So I would suggest to create a unique directory name and store that also in your database in the user-row:

(assuming the username is unique!! )

```
.....
try {
       //- Create a hashed directoryname based on the username
           $user_dir = md5(Input::get('username');


        $user->create(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
            'salt' => $salt,
            'name' => Input::get('name'),
            'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'group' => 1,
            'directory' => $user_dir  //- Add this field also to your database
        ));
        Session::flash('home', '<h3>Registracija uspešna!</h3>');

       //- Create directory, use the right path: absolute/relative
           mkdir(__DIR_.'/path/to/'.$user_dir);

        Redirect::to('mojprofil.php');
}
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

In the section

```
         try {
            $user->create(array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                'salt' => $salt,
                'name' => Input::get('name'),
                'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'group' => 1
            ));
            Session::flash('home', '<h3>Registracija uspešna!</h3>');
```

Add this

```
            mkdir('pathtouserdir'.DS.Input::get('username'));
```

But you should take care, that the username is filter correct.
That no trailling / or ../../ or what ever is in there.
That would change the directory path and could lead to an security issue.
You also might need to set a directory Permissions so the webserver can access it correct.
For more details go to http://php.net/mkdir